# Use Map to get the count of records which have similar picklist values

Tags: apex

I have one custom object Article__c,  having fields Likelihood__c and Impact__c both are picklist.. If two or more records on Article__c have contains same values from these picklist I want to count those records; I'm trying to implement this using Map, my code is,

```
public class CountNumberOfRecords_v2 {

    //List<Article__c> arr = [Select id form Article__c where];
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr = Article__c.Likelihood__c.getDescribe();
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult impa = Article__c.Impact__c.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> pickVals = dfr.getPicklistValues();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> impPickVal = impa.getPicklistValues();
    Map<String,Integer> map1 = new Map<String,Integer>();
    Integer count =0;
    public CountNumberOfRecords_v2()
    {
        for(Schema.PicklistEntry picklist1:pickVals)
        {

            for(Schema.PicklistEntry picklist2:impPickVal)
            {

                map1.put(picklist1.getLabel()+''+picklist2.getLabel(), 0);
            }
        }
        //System.debug('map1 keySet '+map1.keySet());
        //System.debug('map1 values '+map1.values());

        for(Article__c article : [Select id, Likelihood__c, Impact__c from Article__c]){
            if(map1.keySet().contains(article.Likelihood__c+''+article.Impact__c) && map1.get(article.Likelihood__c+''+article.Impact__c)!= null){
                 count = map1.get(article.Likelihood__c+''+article.Impact__c);
                  map1.put(article.Likelihood__c+''+article.Impact__c, count++);

            }

        }
            System.debug('Count --->>> '+count);
            System.debug('Count --->>> '+map1.values()); 
    }

}
```

with this I'm not able to get perfect count.. need some help.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things I noticed. First, you don't need a Map in the first for loop, you can do away with a Set. Second, you are not comparing your article with all keys created earlier. You should add another for loop to check for all keys. Please find the changes below, remember this is not a compiled code you may have to update based on any error.

```
public class CountNumberOfRecords_v2 {
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr = Article__c.Likelihood__c.getDescribe();
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult impa = Article__c.Impact__c.getDescribe();
    List < Schema.PicklistEntry > pickVals = dfr.getPicklistValues();
    List < Schema.PicklistEntry > impPickVal = impa.getPicklistValues();
    Map < String, Integer > map1 = new Map < String, Integer > ();
    Set<String> strImpLik = new Set<String>(); 
    Integer count = 0;
    public CountNumberOfRecords_v2() {
        for (Schema.PicklistEntry picklist1: pickVals) {
            for (Schema.PicklistEntry picklist2: impPickVal) {
                strImpLik.put(picklist1.getLabel() + '' + picklist2.getLabel());
            }
        }
        List<Article__c> lstArticle =  [Select id, Likelihood__c, Impact__c from Article__c];
        for (String key: strImpLik){
            count = 0;
            for (Article__c article: lstArticle) {
                if(key.equals(article.Likelihood__c + '' + article.Impact__c)){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            map1.put(key, count);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `++count` instead `count++`.

> Adds 1 to the value of x, a variable of a numeric type. If prefixed
>   (++x), the expression evaluates to the value of x after the increment.
>   If postfixed (x++), the expression evaluates to the value of x before
>   the increment.

Try this code.

```
public class CountNumberOfRecords_v2 {

    //List<Article__c> arr = [Select id form Article__c where];
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr = Article__c.Likelihood__c.getDescribe();
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult impa = Article__c.Impact__c.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> pickVals = dfr.getPicklistValues();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> impPickVal = impa.getPicklistValues();
    Map<String,Integer> map1 = new Map<String,Integer>();
    Integer count =0;
    public CountNumberOfRecords_v2()
    {
        for(Schema.PicklistEntry picklist1:pickVals)
        {
            for(Schema.PicklistEntry picklist2:impPickVal)
            {
                map1.put(picklist1.getLabel()+''+picklist2.getLabel(), 0);
            }
        }
        //System.debug('map1 keySet '+map1.keySet());
        //System.debug('map1 values '+map1.values());

        for(Article__c article : [Select id, Likelihood__c, Impact__c from Article__c]){
            if(map1.keySet().contains(article.Likelihood__c+''+article.Impact__c) && map1.get(article.Likelihood__c+''+article.Impact__c)!= null){
                 count = map1.get(article.Likelihood__c+''+article.Impact__c);
                 map1.put(article.Likelihood__c+''+article.Impact__c, ++count);
            }
        }
        System.debug('Count --->>> '+count);
        System.debug('Count --->>> '+map1.values()); 
    }

}
```